# Textbox value in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working on sort of a Business Card maker using HTML5 Canvas.
To get custom Name, Address, etc...I'm currently using PROMPT Box...

Right now what I got is :

To define the variables

```
var name = prompt("Votre nom","")
var address = prompt("Votre adresse","")
var title = prompt("Votre titre","")
```

And then to draw it in the canvas :

```
img.onload = function(){
oCtx.drawImage(img,0,0);

oCtx.font = "normal 25px arial";     // different font
oCtx.textBaseline = "top";           // text baseline at the top
oCtx.fillStyle = "#00529e";
oCtx.fillText(address, 283, 138);

oCtx.font = "bold 45px arial";     // different font
oCtx.fillText(name, 283, 350);

oCtx.font = "normal 40px arial";     // different font
oCtx.fillText(title, 283, 410);
};
img.src="back.png";
```

It's working great getting the value from the PROMPT box.
But I would like to do something cleaner, and user textboxes instead.

So the guy would just have to type in a text box next to the Canvas, and when he types in the textbox, it would automaticly update the content of the "name" variable, or "address" or "title".

How can I make this work?

---

EDIT

Here's what I tried...but that is not working :

```
<input type="text" id="testing"/>
```

I would type in this textbox, and then would update :

```
oCtx.fillText(document.getElementById('testing').value), 282, 138);
```

Right now, it's :

```
oCtx.fillText(address, 282, 138);
```

Thanks

---

EDIT 2

I tried :

```
document.getElementById("testing").addEventListener("change", function() {
    var val = document.getElementById("testing").value;
    // now use val in your existing fillText code
});
```

"testing" being the ID of my textbox...
And I changed the fillText to :

```
oCtx.fillText(val, 282, 138);
```

But nothing's happening when I type in the textbox...any idea why?

Comment: What have you tried? **Hint:** You want it to update as you type, so try and find an event on the TextBox you can utilise to run the function you provided above.

Comment: well I have tried : <input type="text" id="testing"/>...and then to get the value : oCtx.fillText(document.getElementById('example_text').value, 283,350);...But it's not working, nothing happens

Comment: @user1388136 - that's because you need an event to trigger the update of your canvas element. You're probably going to need the onblur or onchange event.

Comment: Ok. And how can I make this work using onBlur event? So when I would type, it would update the variable? I'm not sure...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `keypress` handler on your text area:

```
document.getElementById("mytextbox").addEventListener("keydown", function() {
    var val = document.getElementById("mytextbox").value;
    // now use val in your existing fillText code
});
```

Note that you could use the `change` event instead of the `keydown` event, but `change` will only fire after the user moves focus away from the textbox.  The `keypress` event will work similarly to `keydown`, but it won't catch backspaces.

That should get you started!

Comment: It gives me an error when I use your code...maybe there's  something wrong in it?

Comment: Oh, I was missing a closing parenthesis (now edited and fixed).  Was that it?  What is the error?

Comment: Yeah that was it. Now I tried your code but it's not working. Nothing is happening when I type in the textbox. See my EDIT in my first post to see what I did. Thanks!

Comment: Is `oCtx` in the scope of your listener function?  Is the function firing at all?

Comment: I'm not sure of how I should do it. I guess I have to add the function to the oCtx.fillText(val, 282, 138); line...but how should I do it?

Comment: Make sure you make the called to `addEventListener` in a function where `oCtx` is in scope (or for a less elegent solution, just make `oCtx` global).  Maybe add an `alert` or `console.log` in your event function to verify that it is being called.

Comment: It's working...sort of. I tried using ALERT to see if the function is called, and each letter typed was appearing in a ALERT popup...but still, I changed it back to "var val = document.getElementById("mytextbox").value;"...and nothing is showing up in the HTML5 Canvas...Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a valid reference to the canvas context?  Add `console.log(oCtx)` to your event function and see if it is undefined.  If so, that's your problem -- that function *must have a reference to the canvas context in order to draw on it*.  If that function can't see the context variable, it can't draw anything.  If you don't know how to make the context variable exist in the scope of the event listener function, *open a new question* for that new issue, and preferably include a simple example of your non-function code on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: I got it to work using the refresh window function...I used : "oCtx.fillText(document.getElementById("titre").value, 283, 410);"...and I found that when I refresh the window, it appears in the canvas. So it's not 100% like I wanted but still good that way! The thing is that it's only working in Firefox...any idea what could make it work in Safari and Chrome too?

Comment: This discussion has expanded far beyond the scope of the original question.  You should open a new question with these new issues and include your code in it.

Comment: Final comment: when you do post your code in a new question, use the version before you implemented the page-refresh tactic, since that is not a good or generalizable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the new value from the key down event or whatever you then need to clear down the canvas and redraw it.

So

OCtx.clearRect ( x , y , w , h );

//re run the code you used initially with new value