# JS, HTML5 - adding text input value as fillText on canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to play around with HTML5 canvas a little, and I'm just making a fun little web app, but I have gotten stuck.

I want the user to input text into a textbox, then when they press a button, that text gets added to the canvas with TextFill..

Here's what I have:

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var words = document.getElementById("words").value;
        var x = 80;
        var y = 110;

        ctx.font = "bold 36px sans-serif";
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        $('#entertext').click(function(){
            ctx.fillText(words, x, y);
        });
```

So I obviously have a canvas, myCanvas, and a text input box with id=words, and a button with id=entertext...

If you want to totally redo my code, that's completely fine.

Comment: What is your problem? And it would be nice to provide a demo on http://www.jsfiddle.net .

Comment: It just doesn't work. At all. I also found this guy having the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757458/textbox-value-in-html5-canvas .. but nobody on that post helped me either.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fmnBa/ Like this?

Comment: Oh. Yes. Exactly like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Extending from comment, I *guess* that you're assigning `words` in a "static" context like `window.onload`.

And because `document.getElementById("words").value` is a string, it's assigned/copied **by value**, so `words` will very likely to be an empty string, regardless what `document.getElementById("words").value` *later* becomes.

So the solution would be either assign `words` as `document.getElementById("words")`, so it's an object *"pointer"*, or get the value inside `click` event:

```
$('#entertext').click(function(){
    ctx.fillText($("#words").val(), x, y);
});
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fmnBa/).